# C++: Does sqlite3 use errno codes?

Tags: c++, sqlite, errno

I am using the sqlite3 C++ api.  After running

`int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, pSQL, 0, 0, 0);`

which returns a `rc` result of `SQLITE_OK`.

Additionally, I have tested for `errno != 0`.
The result of `cout << strerror(errno) << endl` is consistently:
No such file or directory

In other words, I know that sqlite3 has its own set of "Return Codes" (i.e. SQLITE_OK).  However, does sqlite3 use  errno codes correctly/consistently?  That is, if another part of my application is using the global errno variable, should I be resetting it after every call to `sqlite3_exec`?

Thanks.

---

A more complete example of my code:

```
    const int errno_start = errno;
    if (errno_start > 0) {
        std::cout << "errno=" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "errno_start=" << strerror(errno_start) << std::endl;
    }
    // prepare sql statement
    const char *pSQL;
    pSQL = "CREATE TABLE "
            "IF NOT EXISTS "
            "test1"
            "("
            "id INTEGER,"
            "field VARCHAR(32),"
            "value DOUBLE,"
            "timestamp DATETIME"
            ")";

    //int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, pSQL, callback, 0, &szErrMsg);
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, pSQL, 0, 0, 0);
    const int errno_here1 = errno;
    if (errno_here1 > 0) {
        std::cout << "errno_start=" << strerror(errno_start) << ", errno_here1="
                << strerror(errno_here1) << std::endl;
    }
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << "SQL Error: " << szErrMsg << std::endl;
        sqlite3_free(szErrMsg);
    } else {
        std::cout << "initialize successful" << std::endl;
    }
```

Result from this snippet is:

> errno_start=Success, errno_here1=No such file or directory
>
> initialize successful

Comment: Surely this is documented. If it isn't, then you shouldn't depend on the value of `errno` after any SQLite call; it's very likely to be set by functions called by SQLite.

Answer (score 3):

You should *never* rely on the value in `errno` to persist beyond the next OS call, as pretty much any OS call that can fail (i.e., almost all of them) may set it. At least there's one thing though: `errno` is now usually a thread-local behind the scenes. Still, a library may well set `errno` when you call into it, so it is wise to save the value immediately after a failing system call and ignore it otherwise.

SQLite makes OS calls inside itself (when it accesses the DB file, of course) so it may well set `errno` to virtually anything. The errors that it encounters are handled inside it; if there's something wrong, it will tell you using its own, documented error mechanism. That never includes any information from `errno` as it happens (and in fact that would be non-portable; SQLite runs on Windows as well, and that uses a different error code reporting mechanism).

Comment: This is good advice in general. Any library function you call may be doing a system call that sets errno, and it's not the library's responsibility to either document this, or to reset errno to 0. Example in this case: When using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS to create a new table, then errno can be ENOTFOUND after return from sqlite3_exec, but that's irrelevant to the caller, and thus not documented.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 returns an result code that corresponds to a set of DEFINES as laid out in the [sqlite3 API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html):

```
#define SQLITE_OK           0   /* Successful result */
/* beginning-of-error-codes */
#define SQLITE_ERROR        1   /* SQL error or missing database */
#define SQLITE_INTERNAL     2   /* Internal logic error in SQLite */
#define SQLITE_PERM         3   /* Access permission denied */
#define SQLITE_ABORT        4   /* Callback routine requested an abort */
#define SQLITE_BUSY         5   /* The database file is locked */
#define SQLITE_LOCKED       6   /* A table in the database is locked */
#define SQLITE_NOMEM        7   /* A malloc() failed */
#define SQLITE_READONLY     8   /* Attempt to write a readonly database */
#define SQLITE_INTERRUPT    9   /* Operation terminated by sqlite3_interrupt()*/
#define SQLITE_IOERR       10   /* Some kind of disk I/O error occurred */
#define SQLITE_CORRUPT     11   /* The database disk image is malformed */
#define SQLITE_NOTFOUND    12   /* Unknown opcode in sqlite3_file_control() */
#define SQLITE_FULL        13   /* Insertion failed because database is full */
#define SQLITE_CANTOPEN    14   /* Unable to open the database file */
#define SQLITE_PROTOCOL    15   /* Database lock protocol error */
#define SQLITE_EMPTY       16   /* Database is empty */
#define SQLITE_SCHEMA      17   /* The database schema changed */
#define SQLITE_TOOBIG      18   /* String or BLOB exceeds size limit */
#define SQLITE_CONSTRAINT  19   /* Abort due to constraint violation */
#define SQLITE_MISMATCH    20   /* Data type mismatch */
#define SQLITE_MISUSE      21   /* Library used incorrectly */
#define SQLITE_NOLFS       22   /* Uses OS features not supported on host */
#define SQLITE_AUTH        23   /* Authorization denied */
#define SQLITE_FORMAT      24   /* Auxiliary database format error */
#define SQLITE_RANGE       25   /* 2nd parameter to sqlite3_bind out of range */
#define SQLITE_NOTADB      26   /* File opened that is not a database file */
#define SQLITE_ROW         100  /* sqlite3_step() has another row ready */
#define SQLITE_DONE        101  /* sqlite3_step() has finished executing */
/* end-of-error-codes */
```

Nothing in the API indicates that they use the same error codes as defined in Errno.h. It is simply a coincidence.

[sqlite3 API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) already provides an interface to print a string representation of the error code. I recommend you study the API a little more.

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, I have looked at the [source for sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/src/os_unix.c) and it uses OS functions which set `errno`. That may be why you are seeing `errno` change. [There is no relation between SQLITE result code and errno.](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/two-question-1-sqlite3-s-select-2-errno-and-the-sqlite3-s-result-code-td51489.html)

Comment: I know that sqlite3 returns its own set of error codes.  In my example I show that I test whether the result equals SQLITE_OK. However, sqlite3_exec is *also* changing the global errno variable.  I am trying to understand if sqlite's use of errno is intentional or not.  The reason is because other parts of my program use errno and I want to know if I can safely reset the errno to 0 after calling sqlite3_exec.

Comment: @kmccoy: Ok, but if you put that in your question, my answer would have been different. Your question is not clear in its current form, given your current comment.

Comment: I appreciate your comment.  I have edited my question to hopefully make it more clear. Thank you.